Čech cohomolog of a good cover of the real projective plane
I was reading the Bott/Tu book and trying compute the Čech cohomology of a good cover of the real projective plane (exercise 9.10). The nerve of the cover is dipicted as below: we glue the opposite points of the boundary of the disk $D^2$ to obtain $\mathbb{R}P^2$, and each vertex in the nerve represents an open set, each edge represents an intersection of two opens, each face represents an intersection of three opens.

Denote $\mathfrak{U}$ the cover. From the nerve I can tell that $C^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}^6$ for there are 6 open sets (labeled by 0, 1,..., 5), $C^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}^{15}$ for there are 15 edges (each edge represents an intersection of two open sets, with $\binom{6}{2}=15$), and $C^2(\mathfrak{U},\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}^{10}$ for there are 10 faces, representing the 10 intersections of three opens.
Since $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is connected, we have $H^0(\mathbb{R}P^2)=\mathbb{R}$. Or this can also be read from the fact that $\ker\delta_0=\mathbb{R}$. This is because $(\delta\omega)_{\alpha\beta}=\omega_\beta-\omega_\alpha$, so anything in the kernel will satisfy $\omega_\alpha=\omega_\beta$. If we assign a number to any vertex, say the one labeled by 0, values of all other vertices must be the same number, since all verticies are connected. So we obtain that $\operatorname{img}\delta_0=\mathbb{R}^5$ as the quotient of $C^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathbb{R})$ over $\ker\delta_0$.
Now comes the hard part. I need to figure out the dimension of $\ker\delta_1$. Anything in the kernel satisfy the relation $\omega_{\alpha\beta} + \omega_{\beta\gamma} + \omega_{\gamma\alpha}=0$, or in other words, for any triangle in the nerve, a 1-cocycle is an assignment of 3 real numbers on each side of the triangle, adding up to zero. So for each triangle, we need to assign a number to two of its sides, and the value of the third side is determined, being the negation of the sum of the first two.
Then I tried to give an "independent" assignment, and found that only assigning 5 edges are not sufficient to determine values on other edges. For example, if we assign a value to each edge connecting to vetex 5 (namely 50, 51, 52, 53, 54), we can determine the values on the third edge of each invovled triangle (namely, 02, 21, 13, 34, 40), but we still cannot determine all other values. So I ended up with the conclusion that $\ker\delta_1=\mathbb{R}^6$, hence $H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2)=\ker{\delta_1}/\operatorname{img}\delta_0=\mathbb{R}$.
But from the research (e.g. this answer, this, and this) I did I was told that $H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2)=0$ is trivial. What did I do wrong here?

I think your picture requires some explanation. Are you using the model of $\Bbb RP^2$ as a disk attached to a circle by the doubly-wound boundary map? I.e. $D^2$ quotient by $z\sim z^2$ for $z\in S^1$? That seems reasonable, as a disc is drawn, but then there are $10$ open sets in the cover (and accordingly the cover seems quite inefficient. Moreover no overlaps have been shown! there should be overlaps)

@FShrike thanks for your comment. I updated the first paragraph to add the missing descriptions. You're right I'm using the disk model, and the nerve of the cover is dipicted (instead of the cover itself): each vertex is an open set, and each edge is the intersection of two opens, etc.

One confusing thing here: you say there are $15$ edges, but I count $12$. Are you including the arcs as well? e.g. is there an intersection between $0$ and $1$?

yes I'm including the arcs, so that every face is a triangle. without the arcs, there will be a face with 4 edges (14, 04, 13, 03).

In the below, I use the convention of strictly ordered simplices i.e. I don't consider $\omega_{10}$ or whatever.
One option is to fix bases and just write down the linear maps. You could perform row operations on $\delta_1$ and column operations on $\delta_0$ to decide the kernels and images respectively, for example. But a manual check is possible here.
$H^1(\Bbb RP^2;\Bbb R)=0$ because... let $\omega$ be a $2$-cocyle on the good cover with nerve as shown. I can define $v(0)=0,v(k)=\omega_{0k}$ for $1\le k\le 5$. I must hope that $\delta_0v=\omega$. There are $15$ edges to check equality on; some checks are immediate from the definition of $v$ and the cocyle condition, e.g. on $[0,3]$ or on $[1,3]$ the check is immediate. In the second case, what is important is that $[0,1,3]$ is an actual face!
The nontrivial checks are on the edges $[1,2],[1,5],[2,4],[3,4],[3,5],[4,5]$ because none of these edges are part of a face involving zero, so the cocyle condition does not immediately give us what we want. I consider all of these cases as symmetric, and leave the rest of them as an exercise - I will just check the edge $[1,2]$ for you. I use the red $\to$ blue colour transition to indicate where  cocycle condition has been used for nonadjacent terms, to help you see where things are coming from.
$$\begin{align}(\delta_0v)_{12}&=\omega_{02}-\omega_{01}\\&=\color{red}{\omega_{03}}-\omega_{23}-\color{red}{\omega_{01}}\\&=\color{blue}{\omega_{13}}-\omega_{23}\\&=\omega_{15}-\color{red}{\omega_{35}}-(\omega_{24}-\color{red}{\omega_{34}})\\&=\omega_{15}-\omega_{24}-\color{blue}{\omega_{45}}\\&=\omega_{12}+\color{red}{\omega_{25}}-\omega_{24}-(\color{red}{\omega_{05}}-\color{green}{\omega_{04}})\\&=\omega_{12}-\color{blue}{\omega_{02}}+\color{green}{\omega_{01}+\omega_{14}}-\omega_{24}\\&=\omega_{12}-\omega_{02}+\omega_{01}+\omega_{12}\\&=2\omega_{12}-(\delta_0v)_{12}\\\therefore 2(\delta_0v)_{12}&=2\omega_{12}\end{align}$$
Importantly, I only used the cocycle formula $\omega_{\alpha\beta}+\omega_{\beta\gamma}=\omega_{\alpha\gamma}$ where $[\alpha,\beta,\gamma]$ is actually a face - this is all I am allowed to do.
Now, because the coefficient group $\Bbb R$ has no $2$-torsion we can conclude $(\delta_0v)_{12}=\omega_{12}$ and in general $\delta_0v=\omega$, so that $\ker\delta_1=\mathrm{im}\,\delta_0$ and $H^1(\Bbb RP^2;\Bbb R)=0$. In general, $H^1(\Bbb RP^2;\mathscr{G})\cong\ker(g\mapsto2g)\le\mathscr{G}$, the $2$-torsion subgroup.
Hopefully this helps. You should also be able to compute $H^2(\Bbb RP^2;\Bbb R)=0$, but again the fact your coefficients are in $\Bbb R$ is relevant! In general, $H^2(\Bbb RP^2;\mathscr{G})\cong\mathscr{G}/2\mathscr{G}$.

Thanks for your answer. It is so clear that I can follow all details.

Your cocycle condition is the same as OP's, isn't it? Remember that the standard convention is that $\omega_{\alpha\beta}=-\omega_{\beta\alpha}$.

@TedShifrin You’re right, I misread their $\omega_{\gamma\alpha}$ as $\omega_{\alpha\gamma}$
